# Путь к папке пользователя windows

Tags: windows

Есть идея закинуть всем пользователям папку с портабл firefox и вытащить ярлык на рабочий стол. Как это сделать.

При установке из политики получается c:\username\ff, а в ярлыке жестко зашивается путь к программе

Comment: Для дефолтного браузера лучше всего подходит Google Chrome. Msi-установщик лежит [тут](http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise.msi). Ещё он умеет [пачку](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/topic/1289313) корпоративных фич по управлению.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

%ALLUSERSPROFILE% - Open the All User's Profile

%UserProfile% - Opens you User's Profile

Comment: это называется *Переменные среды Windows* более подробный список можно посмотреть например [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B_Windows)